# My First Plugin

Tags: plugin

I am writing my first EE plugin and have finally hit a roadblock. Here is how it looks

```
        class Thank_you {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->EE = get_instance();

            $entries = $this->EE->db->from('channel_titles')->get();
    }
public function contacts()
    {

        $db2   = $this->EE->load->database('ext_db', TRUE);
        $query = $db2->select('FirstName, LastName, MealType')->order_by('id','DESC')->get('contact',10);

        $contacts = $query->result();

        return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $contacts);
    }
```

So the goal here is to pass an array of contacts to the template and iterate from there. All that I get with

```
{exp:thank_you:contacts}
        {FirstName}
    {/exp:thank_you:contacts}
```

Is an output of {FirstName}. Where am I going wrong on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick comment, I notice you're loading your entire channel_titles table in the constructor. If that's not being used, then you definitely want to get rid of that, since it's adding an extra query to your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through the query result and build an array containing your variables. Using the following code after your query should work.

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
{
    return $this->EE->TMPL->no_results();
}

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $vars[] = array(
        'FirstName'     => $row->FirstName,
        'LastName'      => $row->LastName,
        'url_title'     => $row->MealType
    );
}

return $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $vars);
```

Comment: thx! Makes complete sense now. Need to build out the array, then pass.

Comment: Hey no problem!